# Inserting an asynchronous token in HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, observable

I have an Angular application that communicates with a Node backend. I need to insert a token to the header of every request sent to the API using an HTTP interceptor. To get the token, there's a global service, `AuthService` with the following method: `getToken(): Observable<JWTToken>`.

The issue I'm having is that I can't use `await` inside the `intercept` method because making it `async` would change its returning data type, which is not accepted. To solve it, I'm using the following method:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  // To store the token
  private token;

  constructor(protected router: Router,
    protected authService: AuthService) { }

  setTokenAsync() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authService.getToken().subscribe(jwtToken => {
        this.token = jwtToken.toString();

        resolve(jwtToken.toString());
      });
    });

    return promise;
  }

  async setToken() {
    await this.setTokenAsync();
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Set the token
    this.setToken();
  }

  // Now we can access this.token to inject the token in the header
}
```

Is it an acceptable solution? Is there a simpler way of doing the same?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also get in in the constructor and assign to the variable, maybe using InjectionToken https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I dealt with this situation in a project.

I stored the user state using a **BehaviorSubject** so I can access its current value by using `behavSubjectInstance$.value`.

```js
export class AuthService {

 private currentUserSbj$: BehaviorSubject<any>;

 constructor (private apiService: ApiService) {
   this.currentUserSbj$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
 }

 get currentUser () {
   return this.currentUserSbj$.value;
 }

 setCurrentUser (user) {
   localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
   this.currentUserSbj$.next(user);
 }

 getToken (): string | null {
   return this.currentUser ? this.currentUser.token : null;
 }
}
```

Then, in my jwt interceptor:

```js
   const token: string | null = this.authService.getToken();

    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { [this.AuthHeader]: token },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
            return this.handle401Error(request, next);
          }

          return throwError(err);
        })
      )
```

This worked for me very well, but your case might be different.

Comment: Good method, I'll keep it in mind for future applications. Thanks!